# Python object's __iter__not getting called

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, inheritance

I have a Python 2.7 class (call it Child), that is a child of another class (Parent) that is itself a subclass of dict.

I'm trying to define `__iter__` in Child in the hopes that when someone does a `dict(child_object)` I can control how it is converted to a dict.  I must be misunderstanding something though, because it seems the dict() call is bypassing calling `__iter__` completely and is instead going to the underlying dict.

I did some research and from the dict() method's docs I see that it may be seeing the object as a mapping first, and therefore using that instead of the iterable's `__iter__`.  Is that the case, and if so, is there a way I can overwrite some method that is being called on the mapping?

Comment: Can you add a simple example to your question? That'd make it much easier to follow what you mean.

Comment: Do not inherit from `dict`, but from `collections.UserDict`

Comment: Otherwise special methods won't work, when you override them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `dict()` on a mapping (or use `dictionary.update(...)` passing in a mapping), then Python will not use `__iter__`. Python looks for a `.keys()` method to detect mappings. In that case, if the mapping happens to be a `dict` *or a subclass of dict*, then a fast path is picked that copies key-value pairs directly from the underlying C structures. You can't prevent this with custom Python functions.

Put differently, if you must define a custom mapping type that lets you control how `dict()` copies key-value pairs from it, you should not subclass `dict`. Implement your own mapping type by subclassing [`collections.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping) or [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) or a class from the [`UserDict` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html).

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my suspicions. I saw UserDict docs say "The need for this class has been largely supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from dict" so I went for dict.